# Image Classification how to make program 'wait' for a few seconds if it's a background class

Tags: python, opencv, keras, classification

So i am doing a simple image classification of 4 classes (Class1,2,3 and background)

It's fed live from like a webcam-ish device with lowres so i have it in a While Loop

```
cond = True
While(cond): 
   **code** 

if confidence_value >= 0.98:
            ##print only the class i.e. index 0 is the class and index 1 gives the value
            top_class = top_value[0]
            #stops the while loop
            cond = False
            print('While loop stopped, class detected as:', top_class)
        else:
            print('Unable to decide')
            cond = True
```

Now the code runs in principle but since the background class is the easiest to detect, and the data is constantly pulling, there's a chance it'll detect the background class first before the image is in view. For this i have a simple if brutalistic solution of having the device 'sleep' for about 3s while the image gets into view

The 2nd bit which pertains to this question is sometimes even if e.g. class 1 is in view, it'll detect background class for awhile. I plan to get more data to make it more robust too but for now, is it possible where if it detects the background class, for the code to 'ignore' this class for about maybe 5s before it outputs as background class just in case that the other classes are detected in the meantime.

Comment: do not ever sleep while reading from a camera. -- you need to implement some "state" (boolean/integer variable), and determine when the state *changes*, to govern what your program does and when it does that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put a condition in there and if class is background check the 2nd top class and have some threshold. So say if it detects background see what 2nd best confidence was and use that class instead.